# ssh login with key can't connect although go an ssh key

Tags: linux, ssh, git, autohotkey, ssh-keys

I have my 2 servers that I want to connect one to another with ssh.

I am the user --> userA in serverA,
and I have this config file in .ssh folder

```
Host git
        HostName git.OURSITE.com
        User userB
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git
```

and of course I already created an key named "git" that sits in /home/userA/.ssh folder

and I have user --> userB in serverB
that I added the git.pub from serverA to its /home/userB/.ssh/authorized_keys

now I try to connect userA to serverB as userB

with this -->

```
 ssh git -v
```

and this is my output

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/userA/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/autoUser/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for git
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.initialrewards.com [8.8.8.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/git type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/autoUser/.ssh/git-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e2:b9:42:c4:1e:4d:45:ca:0b:23:38:9b:dd:a6:09:38
debug1: Host 'git.initialrewards.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/userA/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/autoUser/.ssh/git
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

any ideas why it is still asking me for password??

Comment: did you check ownership and permissions of identity file and authorized_keys ? permission must be 600, owner must be appropriate uid.

Answer (score 0):

Check that ~/.ssh has 700 ownership, files in that dir has 600.

But you should also check the ownership of your HOME directory, and parent directories. They should NOT be writable by the group or other.

This last requirement is depending on the sshd config, but that is the default.